# Counting up inside of functions

Tags: excel

I have a function that reads =INDIRECT($A1&"!a2")I would like to have a few hundred columns that will count up so the next one will read =INDIRECT($A1&"!b2") without needing to modify each one. Dragging it just copies the previous cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Index():

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT($A1 & "!2:2"),COLUMN(A:A))
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This was a life saver.